# Bootstrap modal in php loop

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a php loop of users that opens a modal for each one individually. The problem is that nothing happens when "choices" is changed.
I want to display its own fields in relation_fields for each modal separately by changing "choices".
Each of the select tags are created with the select2 library, which also does not work.

```
<?php foreach ( $users as $user ): ?>
    <div class="modal fade" id="test-<?php echo $user->id ?>" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false"
         tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel">modal</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="post" id="new_test<?php echo $user->id ?>" class="new_test_modal">
                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                <select class="form-select" id="choices">
                                    <option value="">numbers</option>
                                    <option value="one">01</option>
                                    <option value="two">02</option>
                                    <option value="three">03</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 relation_fields" style="display: none">
                                <div class="col-12" id="one_search" style="display: none">
                                    <select name="one_search_list" id="one_search_list" class="form-control"></select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12" id="two_search" style="display: none">
                                    <select name="two_search_list" id="two_search_list" class="form-control"></select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-12" id="three_search" style="display: none">
                                    <select name="three_search_list" id="three_search_list"
                                            class="form-control"></select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#choices').on('change', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            const relatedOption = $('#choices option:selected').val();
            if (relatedOption !== '') {
                $('.relation_fields').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('.relation_fields').slideUp();
            }
            if (relatedOption === 'one') {
                $('#one_search').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $('#one_search').css('display', 'none');
            }
            if (relatedOption === 'two') {
                $('#two_search').css('display', 'block')
            } else {
                $('#two_search').css('display', 'none')
            }
            if (relatedOption === 'three') {
                $('#three_search').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $('#three_search').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    }).change();
</script>
```

Run jquery separately modal in php loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the id attribute of an HTML element have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-the-id-attribute-of-an-html-element-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: @bassxzero no...!

Comment: pretty sure it does. `<select class="form-select" id="choices">` is inside a loop....

Comment: As @bassxzero said with the link - your `id`s are not unique. Since you're generating modals within a `foreach` loop, you're repeating the `id` value for multiple elements - `#statickBackdropLabel`, `#choices`, `#one_search`, `#one_search_list`, etc. Since you're using both Bootstrap and jQuery, consider making an *external modal* - place your HTML and jQuery logic there, and open the modal from another file / page. For example, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75011692/6133426).